# Column multiple SliverList In CustomScrollView

Tags: flutter

```
                CustomScrollView(
                  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                  slivers: [
                    SliverToBoxAdapter(
                      child: Container(height: 600, width: 400, color: Colors.red),
                    ),
// HERE I NEED MULTIPLE SliverLists VERTICALLY - BEGIN
                    Column(
                      children:[
                        SliverList(
                           delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
                             (_, index) => SomeExpensiveWidget(index),
                             childCount: 10000,
                           ),
                        ),
                        SliverList(
                           delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
                             (_, index) => SomeCustomRowWidget(index),
                             childCount: 10000,
                           ),
                        ),
                      ]
                    ),
// THIS DOESNT WORK - END
                    SliverToBoxAdapter(
                      child: Container(height: 600, width: 400, color: Colors.red),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
```

I have a `CustomScrollView` and it is scrolling horizontally. Due to some reason I need to have multiple SliverList in a Column widget. I am trying to create a 2D grid and I can't use `SliverGrid` because my widgets inside `SomeCustomRowWidget` only works when they are in a Row (elements in row shrink and get bigger according to some condition). I am trying to have multiple `SliverList` in a Column to give the illusion of a grid but so far its not working because `Column` widget works with normal widgets. There is no `SliverColumn` or something like that. How may I position SliverLists as if they are in a `Column`?

Answer (score 0):

there is a widget let you put any widget as slivers

wrap the widgets you want to show with `SliverToBoxAdapter` like this

```
SliverToBoxAdapter(
child: YourWidget(),
),
```

it will just let adapt your other widgets to the slivers family.

Comment: This is not my problem, my problem  is that I want to make a Column out of SliverLists